# How to customize the layout of a validate message error in a flutter form

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to do something like this

[image: i'm trying to do something like this]

this is my Form

`Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _controllerEmail,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter your E-mail",
                                  labelText: "E-mail",
                                ),
                                // ignore: missing_return
                                validator: (text) {
                                  if (text.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'E-mail is required';
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),`

this is what i'm getting  the default error message,anyway to change that?

[image: this is what i'm getting]

Answer (score 1):

TLDR : not with the InputDecoration, Form, FormField framework to validate and display error.

The beauty of Flutter being open source is that you can check the source code for yourself to get the idea. [Here is the widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/33e7af728ade0387ae4c97ded6f3b4a27429f3e2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L280) that displays the `errorText`. The only modification you can do it changing the style using `errorStyle`in `InputDecoration`.

If you really want to achieve something like the one mentioned in your question, I suggest you use [bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble) package to build that error bubble and separate mechanism to validate the form.